# Time of the verb "own"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

In the following sentence I would like to know if the verb "own" should be in the singular or the plural form in American English.

> This survey was designed to provide a representative sample of the
>   population that **own/owns** at least one car.

Comment: This post contains two different questions: one about the choice of verbs and one about singular vs. plural. Could you please choose *one*?

Comment: @Stephie thank you for your comment. I have edited the question.

Comment: Erm, the rule here is *one question per post* (unless they are related, which yours aren’t).

Comment: @Stephie thank you for your comment. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you have solved the doubt about have/own. According to the [Oxford Thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/own), they are synonyms.

In relation with **population**, let's check the Cambridge Dictionary

[**population**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/population)
noun [ C, **+ sing/pl** verb ] 
​

> all the people living in a particular country, area, or place

Notice that I have highlighted +sing/pl. What does this mean?

[**+sing/pl**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/help/codes.html)

> A noun that refers to a group of people acting collectively. **When used
>   in the singular** it can be followed by either **a singular or a plural
>   verb in British English.** In American English a singular verb is
>   preferred.

So, it depends on the kind of English that you want to use, British or American. Both options are correct in British English.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RubioRic. But now I got a little confused by reading Carter Cali 's answer. Is "owns" really preferred when used to indicate ownership/possession? Clarifying: I'm using this type of sentence in American English.

Comment: @R.Joe I don't get what Carter Cali means there. According to the Cambridge Dictionary to have = to own in your context https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have If you are using American English: owns is the preferred choice. But you can also use "has" and they will understood you perfectly.

Comment: Thank you @RubioRic. But according to your answer, the singular verb is preferred in American English. So doesn't this mean that "own" should be preferred over "owns"?

Comment: @R.Joe A singular form is preferred. owns is the singular one. He/She/It owns.